# Node Application compiles when running

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a typescript application which runs fine in `dev` mode when running through `ts-node`, But after build when I try to run it gives some unusual `warnings` or `errors`

my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,  
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,       
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "esModuleInterop":true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true, 
  },
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./docs", "cs-keycloak-theme", "./build"]
}
```

My application directory structure looks like
[image]

And When I am building my application and running it, it shows like this
[image]

The cpx I am doing is copying some JS file from `src/` to `build/` becasuse these are code generated by another script which can not run on every machine.

The point its running fine when i say `ts-node src/server.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the configuration in tsconfig that will allow `JS` files to be imported inside the project.

Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside your project, instead of just .ts and .tsx files. For example, this JS file:

```
// @filename: card.js
export const defaultCardDeck = "Heart";
```

When imported into a TypeScript file will raise an error:

```
// @filename: index.ts
import { defaultCardDeck } from "./card";
 
console.log(defaultCardDeck);
```

Imports fine with allowJs enabled:

```
// @filename: index.ts
import { defaultCardDeck } from "./card";
 
console.log(defaultCardDeck);
```

This flag can be used as a way to incrementally add TypeScript files into JS projects by allowing the .ts and .tsx files to live along-side existing JavaScript files.

For more details check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs).